# when does iOS build distributed via crashlytics expire?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

iOS build distributed via Test Flight expires in 90 days.
Does iOS build distributed via Crashlytics also has a limitation of 90 days?

Answer (score 6):

Builds distributed through Crashlytics will expire when the distribution certificate they were signed with expires. You can check that expiration date by opening Keychain Access, going to My Certificates in the bottom-left pane, and finding your iPhone Distribution certificate.